# Count posts as categories PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, count, categories

I've this code...

```
$lesson = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE gr='exrcs' ORDER BY title");
$flesson = mysql_fetch_array($lesson);
do {
    printf("<a href='exrcs?cat=%s'>%s</a>",$flesson['id'],$flesson['title']);
   } while ($flesson = mysql_fetch_array($lesson));
```

This code will be **"`HTML, CSS, PHP`"** and other...

But I want this **"`HTML (2), CSS (14), PHP(8)`"** and other...

Here `(2),(14),(8)` amount posts on categories

Comment: edit your code and format it in code tag.

Comment: Stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 1):

Update your query:

```
SELECT title, count(id) total FROM categories WHERE gr='exrcs' group by title ORDER BY title
```

or

```
SELECT concat(title,' (', count(id) ,')') as title FROM categories WHERE gr='exrcs' group by title ORDER BY title
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  count and group by

```
"SELECT cat as title , count(*)  FROM categories 
WHERE gr='exrcs' group by title  ORDER BY title"
```

Comment: If you category column is named cat  .. then using cat as title  ... you should obtain what you are looking for .. i have update the answer  .. if you use others name show your table schema

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT CONCAT(C.title,'(',COUNT(*),')') FROM categories C INNER JOIN post P ON C.ID= P.cat_id GROUP BY c.title"
```